# AndroidAnnotations with IntelliJ IDEA and 'android-apt' Gradle plugin : "Could not find property 'androidTestCompile' on configuration container"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-annotations

I am trying to make a *Hello World* with **AndroidAnnotations** and Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA.
(I only have some experience with IntelliJ, all the other stuff is completely new to me.)

I have created a new *Gradle: Android Module* in IntelliJ IDEA and then edited `build.gradle` per "[Configure your gradle](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle)" in the AndroidAnnotations' [official guide](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Configuration#gradle).

Unfortunatelly, **I get this error saying I have no idea what** (on line 18: `apply plugin: 'android-apt'`)

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':Hello'.
> Could not find property 'androidTestCompile' on configuration container.
```

---

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal() // cache (USER_HOME/.m2 folder)

}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt' // This is the line of the error
def AAVersion = '3.0.1'  // IS THIS OK?

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.hello.app'

        // If you're using Android NBS flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
        // resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    // This is only needed if you project structure doesn't fit the one found here
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            // java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'build/generated/source/apt/${variant.dirName}']
            // resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            // assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Version Compatibility.

**`androidTestCompile`** was introduced in version **0.9.0** of the Android Gradle plugin (and I was using **0.7.+** here), so 0.9.0 is the minimum one should use with `android-apt`'s newer versions (**3.0.1** here).

---

Also, you might have some more problems with incompatible versions of all these tools.

[Here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility) is a table of **version compatibility** among **Android Studio, Android Gradle plugin** and **Gradle**